# How to combine two Javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are the two javascripts that i am trying to combine in the header of my website, the first script is for my tab menu and the second is for my content slider. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $('#tabs').tabs();

            $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
                function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
                function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
            );

        });
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $().ready(function() {
            $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
        });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#tabs').tabs();

        $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
            function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
        );

        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the jquery library twice, once version 1.3.2 and once 1.6.2. I'd suggest removing the lowest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   $().ready(function() {
        $('#tabs').tabs();

        $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
            function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
        );

        $('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider();

    });

</script>
```

You can try this one. And you have added jquery Library twice no need to do this. Sometime it's create problem and more jquery Library reduce the page load performance, so always careful about adding jquery Library.